# Increment Month in Excel and convert to Text

Tags: excel, text, increment

I am trying to calculate fiscal months from a date and convert it to text in Excel 2010 and use the formula as a Site Column in SharePoint 2010.

Our fiscal month runs from the 19th of one month to the 18th of the next month.

So, for example if the the date is 12/19/2012, the fiscal month would be January.

I used the following formula, but I all I get as a result is Jan.

```
=IF(DAY(A2)>=19,TEXT(MONTH(A2)+1,"mmm"),TEXT(MONTH(A2),"mmm"))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `MONTH` function because your formula is returning a number 1 to 12 which is deemed to be a date in January 1900, hence you always get `Jan`, use `EDATE` to increment the month like this:

`=IF(DAY(A2)>=19,TEXT(EDATE(A2,1),"mmmm"),TEXT(A2,"mmmm"))`

....or you can use this shorter version for the same result

`=TEXT(EDATE(A2-18,1),"mmmm")`

That will give you **December** for 18th December but **January** for the 19th - clearly you can use "mmm" if you just want the short form of the month

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same effect without using EDATE? I only ask because I want to use it in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Well, in that first one you don't really need EDATE, you know that if DAY(A2)>=19 that adding 13 would be certain to give you a date in the next month (it doesn't matter which date), so this version works too: `=IF(DAY(A2)>=19,TEXT(A2+13,"mmmm"),TEXT(A2,"mmmm"))`, or shorten again by using this version: `=TEXT(A2+IF(DAY(A2)>18,13,0),"mmmm")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mmmm` for the full name.